# what is the difference between f-dropdown and dropdown

Tags: html, drop-down-menu, zurb-foundation

I am using foundation to build the website.

I am wondering what is the difference between class="f-dropdown" and class="dropdown"?

The Grid Templated page here(http://foundation.zurb.com/templates.html) used the class="dropdown", while the documentation here(http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/dropdown.html) used class="f-dropdown".

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"dropdown" is used for drop-down in navigation bar

"f-dropdown" is for drop-down plugin which you can use  with any element on page